# Named function expression + 'F' in javascript?

Tags: javascript

As I was reading [**this article**](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/function-declarations.html) about `javascript patterns`/`anti patterns`-

Then - I saw this part :

```
// named function expression + 'F'
//     Benefits:
//     1. Get's rid of (anonymous function) in stack traces
//     2. Recurse by calling the name + 'F'
//     3. Doesn't break an IE (well, unless there's a function name collision of the                               sort described here: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/366#issuecomment-242134)


 var getData = function getDataF () {}; //<----- notice ends with F
```

As opposed to the prev example :

```
 var getData = function getData () {};
```

**Question :**

What is this *thing* with  functions ending with `F` ? IS there really differnce if function ends with  F or not (according to the article  , there is)? what is the official name for this psotfix with F?

In short : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwvWa.jpg

## edit

I didnt see that the variable name **is the same**  as  the function name
which is apprently what they wanted to say...

Comment: @dystroy they distinguish between `myfunc` vs `myfuncF` that's what the question is actually about. ( removed the word `syntax` as it probably  confusing)

Comment: What's your question exactly ? If there's a difference ? Yes there is.

Comment: @dystroy My question is well designed and asked. What is the formal name for this "F" postfix thing ? didn't find in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to debug, because it's an anonymous function and no function name appears in the stack trace (e.g. Firebug):

```
var getData = function () {
};
```

Better to debug, because the function name appears in the stack trace, **but** this breaks IE because the function has the same name as the variable:

```
var getData = function getData () {
};
```

Better to debug, because the function name appears in the stack trace, **and** IE won't break because the function has **not the same name as the variable**. The downside is, the variable has another name as the function (might be confusing). Instead of the "F" you could use any other character (but it's better to always use the same character to avoid confusion):

```
var getData = function getDataF () {
};
```

Comment: allow me to empesize !

Answer (score 0):

This names the function (more formally, [it gives it an *identifier*](http://es5.github.io/#x13) which could also be called from the scope of the function) :

```
var getData = function getDataF () {
  throw 48;
}
```

It makes a difference when the functions is passed as value :

```
var getData = function () { throw 48; }
getData.call();
// ==> "getData" in the stack trace

var getData = function () { throw 48; }
(getData).call();
// ==> "anonymous function" in the stack trace

var getData = function getDataF () { throw 48; }
(getData).call();
// ==> "getDataF" in the stack trace
```

It also allows the function to be called from its own scope. This is frequently used for recursions. Instead of

```
function dive(i){
  console.log(i);
  if (--i) dive(i);
}
dive(3);
```

You can do

```
function dive(i){
  console.log(i);
  if (--i) dive(i);
})(3);
```

which is cleaner and doesn't pollute the external scope.

Comment: no. that's not what they meant. you didnt see the article as the former example already explains that

Comment: @RoyiNamir Your question is really really unclear. What don't you understand in the "article" ?

Comment: I dont think my question is unclear.  I think it's very clear. apprently they distinguish between 2 situations. look at the image above ^^.

Comment: You wont believe it. I just saw that the variable name is the same as the function name. clearly this is what they wanted to show. ( and to warn)... dont you think I already knew the unnamed function vs named function ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between var getData = function getData () or var getData = function getDataF (), both are named function expressions.
The good thing about this pattern is.

1. It provides you visibility on the callstack during debugging because name property of the function object will be set.
2. It provides you the ability to recurse because using the name property you can call the same function recursively via the inner scope of the functions e.g

   function faa() {} // declaration

   var baa = function () {}; // expression

   var caa = function caa() {}; // named expression

   faa.name; // "faa"

   baa.name; // ""

   caa.name; // "caa"